# Meaning of Urdhwaretam in Narayana Sukta

Tags: vedas, vishnu, hymn

The following mantra appears at the end of Narayana Sukta:

> ṛtagṃ satyaṃ pa’raṃ brahma puruṣa’ṃ kṛṣṇapiṅga’lam |
>
> ūrdhvare’taṃ vi’rūpā’kṣaṃ viśvarū’pāya vai namo nama’ḥ ||

All the words appearing in the mantra denote a quality of Narayana: ṛtam indicates that He is order, satyam means He is truth, virupaksha means that He is all-seeing etc. In the same vein, what does Urdhwaretam mean?

Answer (score 3):

It [means](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=Urdhva&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) either-

ऊर्ध्वरेतadj                  .Urdhvareta living in chastity

ऊर्ध्वरेतadj                   .Urdhvareta     keeping the semen above